# plsql propagating/raising exception from a subprogram/unit

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Lets say i am calling a plsql procedure from another procedure (all defined in the same package)

I am trying to raise an application error from proc1 to be displayed on a c# program(proc1 will be the entry call) when something goes wrong. Its straightforwrd when an exception happens within proc1. But how to propagate the same error that gets raised in proc2?

Do i have to declare the same user_exception EXCEPTION in proc1 as well? Or 
should i have a global exception variable at the package level ? Whats the standard practice? 
(pls ignore any code errors such an exception_init etc..) I had only included the code for the concept..

```
     create or replace procedure proc1 is 
     begin

          --some plsqlcode
          proc2();

     exception
       raise_application_error( ???? );
     end proc1;

    create or replace procedure proc2 is 
    user_exception EXCEPTION;
    begin
    --do something
    if (somefalse condition) then 
       raise user_exception
    exception
      when user_exception then 
        --do some error handling
        raise;
    end proc2;
```

I hope i was clear in framing the question. Thanks in advance for suggestions/tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a package, standard practice is to declare exception in a package.

```
create or replace package pkg is
  user_exception exception;

  procedure proc1;
  procedure proc2;
end pkg;

create or replace package body pkg is
  procedure proc1 is
  begin
    proc2;
  exception
    when user_exception then
      raise;
  end;

  procedure proc2 is
  begin
    raise user_exception;
  end;
end pkg;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to declare the exception so it's visible in both procedures:

```
user_exception EXCEPTION;

create or replace procedure proc1 is 
begin

     --some plsqlcode
     proc2();

exception
  when user_exception then             -- added
    raise_application_error( ???? );   -- added
  when others then
    raise_application_error( ???? );
end proc1;

create or replace procedure proc2 is 
begin
--do something
if (somefalse condition) then 
   raise user_exception
exception
  when user_exception then 
    --do some error handling
    raise;
end proc2;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Bob, Is that the standard practice? I can definitely declare the exception at the package spec.

Comment: If the exception doesn't need to be visible outside the package body (i.e. is only used by procedures within the package body) I'd just put it in the package body. And yes, I'd say this is standard practice - I use similar declarations in packages I write all the time. Share and enjoy.